# Approaches for embedding script required data in markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

What approaches can be used to embed additional meta data in HTML markup, where that data is required by client side javascript.

Some simple examples of what I mean:

- A list of contacts which when clicked shows their position in a map.  ie: how to associate a lat/long with each contact.
- A set of images which when clicked pops up a draggable rubberband for selecting a cropping rectangle.  ie: how to associate that clipping rectangle with each image.

The approaches I've seen so far:

1. A separate in-page block of javascript/json with a dictionary containing this additional information.
2. Using rel attributes to store strings that are then parsed by the script.

What other approaches are there?  What are the pros/cons of each?

Another way to think of this: is there an easy way to pre-populate the `.data` property of a jQuery object directly from markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [JQuery Metadata Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata) for this purpose. There are several ways to generate the data (see the documentation).

I can't talk about the pros/cons of this approach because this is the only one I ever used, but it was suitable in every scenario when I needed to add some metadata.